# How to calculate mode from database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mode

I have county name, year and price. I am trying to calculate mode however I am not sure how, I am looking for a simplest possible command.

```
SELECT COUNT(Price_€)AS Frequency FROM `sales20102015` WHERE Date_of_Sale LIKE '%2010%' AND County = 'Monaghan'
```

this will show a number of total rows in the database...

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will select the single most common price, and the number of occurences:

```
SELECT Price_€, COUNT(Price_€) FROM `sales20102015` 
WHERE Date_of_Sale LIKE '%2010%' AND County = 'Monaghan'
GROUP BY Price_€
ORDER BY COUNT(Price_€) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to mysql database here. If that is the case then the below will give you the mode

```
SELECT x, COUNT( * )
FROM t1
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```